# Установить Windows 7 после Linux не удаляя его

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dual-boot, wine, lubuntu

Железо:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 430  @ 2.27GHz
4Gb RAM
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)

Раньше у меня стояла Windows и я мог играть в игры, например Emperor Battle for Dune, WarCraft III, Ведьмак 1, WoW и т.д. Даже Сайрим запускался в небольшом окне.

Потом я перешел на Lubuntu, так как очень шустрая ОС. И по работе меня полностью устраивает.

Но вновь захотелось поиграть. Wine - хорошая штука, на нем можно запустить очень старую Windows-игру, которая уже не хочет запускаться на новом Windows (7 и старше). Устанавливал я через POL - игры запускались, но сильно лагали и были проблемы с текстурами.

У меня появились мысли, что как-то еще нужно правильно установить или настроить драйвер на видеокарту в Wine. Или как-то с параметром запускать игру через Wine, что бы она работала.

Но если мне не помочь, тогда скажите, пожалуйста, как установить Windows 7 после Ubuntu (Lubuntu), не стирая и не удаляя последнюю.

Lubuntu устанавливал не разбивая раздел, т.е. на весь раздел точка монтирования "/" и файловая система btrfs.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Все таки можно установить Windows после установки Linux и использовать две ОС. Для этого нужно две USB-Flash ну или одну USB-Flash и второй ПК для записи нужного загрузчика.

1. Загружаемся с установочной USB-Flash для Linux (в моем случае Lubuntu). Теперь смотрим внимательно. Когда загрузился Linux из флешки и есть интернет, т.е. Wi-Fi или LAN работает, тогда все нормально. В противном случае загружайтесь в ОС з HDD и качайте [Boot repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) и можете смело записать его как загрузчик на USB-Flash с Linux. Также пока у Вас рабочая ОС, рекомендую скачать все драйвера для вашего дистрибутива Windows.
2. Запускаем с флешки с Linux или с Boot repair программу GParted. В начале диска отделяем свободное пространство для Windows. Обязательно вначале! Потому что, если отделить с конца диска, то система все равно 1 Gb отделит в начале и это все займет одинаковое к-во времени. Отделять будет долго, в зависимости от загруженности диска, т.е. будет всю инфу переносить.
3. Грузимся с флешки с Windows и устанавливаем его на свободное пространство. Я его не разделял на C: и D: т.к. мне нужен Windows только для игрушек.
4. Обратили внимание, что ПК грузится только в Windows. Не паникуем. Загружается с флешки с Linux или с Boot repair. Если флешка с Linux и работает интернет, то устанавливаем сюда Boot repair:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   ```

   Запускает установленный Boot repair и после анализа в появившимся окне выбираем Recommended repair. Если флешка с Boot repair, то процесс восстановление GRUB уже начался.
   Теперь при запуске ПК у будет появляться Выбор ОС на 8 сек. По умолчанию будет Ubuntu. Если нужно поменять конфигурацию загрузчика, то это совсем другая история.

Answer (score 1):

Вопреки коментатору ниже- можно.
Просто ставь, при установке урезая диск с максимальным обемом (попутно, он же должен быть sda2, но тут могу ошибаться).
После штатной установки, открой .cmd от администратора и введи:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Ето если Win10, в ином случае по запросу в гугл: `Windows, как востановить Grub`, over9000 статей.

Answer (score -3):

Нельзя установить Windows после установки Linux. Загрузчик Windows всегда затирает загрузчик Linux, после этого невозможно будет загрузить Linux. Наоборот можно. Надо сначала установить Windows, при установке разметить диск таким образом, чтобы осталось свободное место для Linux. После установки Windows установить в свободный раздел Linux. При этом Linux автоматически определит наличие Windows и поставит меню для выбора операционной системы в загрузку. Сейчас же вы можете попробовать установить Windows в виртуальной машине, в KVM или VirtualBox.